# How do I clean a dart build? And modify the g++ flags?

Tags: dart

I'm cross-building dart for armel (a client hired me to solve problems there)

I'm building on ubuntu 14.04 (the armel gcc/g++ is 4.7.3).

I want to take out -Werror since I'm seeing:

```
  /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ '-DDART_NO_SNAPSHOT' '-DDART_PRECOMPILER' '-DTARGET_ARCH_ARM' '-DNDEBUG' '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' -Iruntime  -Werror -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wvla -Woverloaded-virtual -g3 -ggdb3 -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fstack-protector -Wa,--noexecstack -marm -mfpu=vfp -Wno-psabi -fno-strict-overflow -O3 -ffunction-sections -fno-omit-frame-pointer  -MMD -MF out/ReleaseXARM/.deps/out/ReleaseXARM/obj.target/libdart_vm_nosnapshot/runtime/vm/compiler.o.d.raw  -c -o out/ReleaseXARM/obj.target/libdart_vm_nosnapshot/runtime/vm/compiler.o runtime/vm/compiler.cc
In file included from runtime/vm/isolate.h:18:0,
                 from runtime/vm/growable_array.h:15,
                 from runtime/vm/compiler.h:9,
                 from runtime/vm/compiler.cc:5:
runtime/vm/thread.h: In static member function 'static dart::RawError* dart::Compiler::CompileClass(const dart::Class&)':
runtime/vm/thread.h:167:17: error: variable 'thread' might be clobbered by 'longjmp' or 'vfork' [-Werror=clobbered]
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [out/ReleaseXARM/obj.target/libdart_vm_nosnapshot/runtime/vm/compiler.o] Error 1
BUILD FAILED
```

I'm working with this dart git tree:

```
commit 1d028eed8dfa00ac9d4ff685e61b01e6909dbeb4
Author: Paul Berry <paulberry@google.com>
Date:   Wed Nov 30 12:28:51 2016 -0800
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an actual bug in the code. One way to fix it would be to mark the `thread` variable `volatile`.